# Як перекласти слово breadcrumbs в контексті інтернет-сайту

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

З огляду на [усталені переклади системи Drupal](https://localize.drupal.org/node/186) слово *breadcrumbs* перекладається як *хлібні крихти*, що є довшим і часом заважає формувати пункти меню через довгу назву.

Відповідно, які можна знайти відповідники, щоб дане слово було одним і не ламало інтерфейси?

Comment: можливо [сюжети](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0) з грецької міфології стануть у нагоді

Answer (score 4):

*Хлібні крихти*, на мій погляд, не відповідають смислу терміну (як і, наприклад, *cookie*).

**(Оновлено)** *Хлібні крихти* - це посилання на казку, коли діти, яких заводили у ліс щоб їх там покинути, залишали за собою камінці або хлібні крихти, щоб знайти потім шлях додому.

Пропоную варіант **навігація** та його похідні:  **навігаційний шлях**, **навігаційний маршрут**, **рядок навігації**.

Comment: Хлібні крихти -  це посилання на казку, коли діти, яких заводили у ліс щоб їх там покинути, залишали за собою камінці або хлібні крихти, щоб знайти потім шлях додому.

Comment: "Строка" - російське слово, і навіть калька "стрічка" насправді означає "стрічку в коси" чи "стрічка для друкарської машинки". Послідовність символів - це "рядок", з друкарської термінології. Оскільки зміна тільки 6 символів, Stack Exchange не дає мені виправити це у Вас у відповіді, то ж змушений тут коментарем :)

Comment: *навігація* відповідає на питання "як дістатися з пункту А в пункт Б", тоді як *breadcrumbs* — "як повернутися в пункт А, якщо вже дістався пункту Б", тому ці терміни не рівнозначні

Comment: @NashBridges, згоден, можна ще спробувати погратись зі словом "зворотній" - наприклад, "зворотній шлях", "зворотня навігація" тощо.

Answer (score 2):

На відміну [від Nash Bridges](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/345#comment866_351), я не вважаю *навігацію* і *breadcrumbs* чимось різним. Адже навігація — це не лише, [власне, пересування з пункту А в пункт Б](http://sum.in.ua/s/navighacija), а й відповідні [галузь знань, майстерність, навички](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F). А breadcrumbs — це не суто інструмент повернення назад (як на мене, це зовсім не інструмент повернення назад — для повернення назад є кнопка « Back»), а радше один із (найбазовіших, я би сказав) засобів навігації. В тій же панелі, де знаходяться breadcrumbs, можуть розташовуватися й інші засоби навігації, наприклад, пошук, іконки переходу на найпопулярніші сторінки тощо.

Тому я би особисто назвав breadcrumbs **навігаційним рядком**. (Але я би не використовував назву *навігаційний шлях*, бо слово *шлях* хоча в своєму IT-шному значенні і може позначати ієрархічну характеристику поточного місцеположення (наприклад, [шлях файлу](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83): стільниця > диск D: > папка «Робота» > файл «CV.odt»), все ж в основному значенні — це саме спосіб пересування від пункту А до пункту Б, тобто саме те, від чого Nash Bridges хотів застерегти; і тим більше — не *навігаційний маршрут*.) Приблизно згодні зі мною перекладачі KDE, що перекладають *breadcrumbs* як *навігаційна панель*.

Слово *рядок* непогано описує серію вкладених одне в одного елементів. (Ще краще її описує слово *ієрархія*, але слово *ієрархія* не в'яжеться зі словом *навігаційна*.) Можливо: *навігаційний стек* (при умові, що користовачі знають, що таке *стек*) або *навігаційний [стіс](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/stek)* (чи *навігаційна [стопа](http://sum.in.ua/s/stis)*).

Примітка: я виходжу з припущення, що **правильні** breadcrumbs, незважаючи на свою дуже невдалу назву в англійській мові, показують поточне положення **через серію вкладених одна в одну категорій**, а не **переліком проміжних точок, якими користувач сюди потрапив**. Не треба плутати вихід на рівень вище і повернення на крок назад. Мій досвід, як користувача, каже мені, що breadcrumbs треба будувати через перше (а друге — це просто *історія*, яка у випадку якихось випадкових переміщень чи потрапляння прямо з пошуку мало розкаже користовачу про поточне положення). Хоча у випадку неоднозначності ієрархії можна показувати breadcrumbs контекстно.

[На Словотворі](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bredkrambs) ще пропонують такі варіанти:

- *вертланки* (довго не міг зрозуміти, щo це, потім здогадався — вертальні ланки), *зарубки*, *сліди* — знов таки, обіграють у назві повернення назад, а не вихід вгору (може, такий разновид навігаційних інструментів теж іноді корисний, але він вже має свою назву — *[навігаційна] історія* або *[навігаційний] журнал*);
- *хлібокрихти*, *окрайки*, *крихітки* — на додачу до недоліків попередній трьох, ще й [посилаються на казку про Гензель і Ґретель](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D1%96_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C), тобто наслідують всі можливі помилки англійської назви (я нічого не маю проти Гензель і Гретель, [нитки Аріадни](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0) й інших казок/легенд, але все ж ми маємо визнати, що сучасні користувачі не завжди настільки ерудовані і такі метафори часто лише збивають їх з пантелику);
- *перебуванок* — вже краще, але саме по собі нічим не допомагає користувачу, бо є фактично вигаданим синонімом до слів *розташування*, *позиція*, *локація*; може, *ієрархія перебуванку*?

[В українській Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0) наразі пропонують *навігаційну стежку* і *навігаційний ланцюг* — але, по-моєму, вони мають ті ж вади, що й *шлях*/*маршрут* — асоціюються з « Back», а не з « Up».

Висновок з цієї суто особистої відповіді — вирішіть, що Ви хочете, який різновид багатозначного (і невдалого) терміну *breadcrumbs*:

- якщо шлях назад — то це називається *[навігаційна] історія* або *[навігаційний] журнал*;
- якщо шлях вгору (тобто до кореня) — то я пропоную: *навігаційний рядок*, *навігаційний стіс* (*навігаційна стопа*), *ієрархія перебуванку* (?) або просто *навігаційна панель*.